# Fast Quaternion-Vector Multiplication with other Transformation Matrices

Tags: math, matrix, 3d, quaternions, rotational-matrices

I am currently trying to find an equivalent for the following equation:

```
vec_res = inverse(VM) * (q * (VM * vec_input) * conjugate(q))
```

where *VM* is a standard view matrix , *q* is a normalized quaternion, and *vec_input* a vector.

In the form:

```
vec_res = A * vec_input;
```

or

```
vec_res = q' * vec_input * conjugate(q');
```

From https://molecularmusings.wordpress.com/2013/05/24/a-faster-quaternion-vector-multiplication/ I am already calculating

```
vec_res = inverse(VM) * q * VM * vec_input * conjugate(q)
```

as

```
pN = (VM * vec_input);
vec3 tempVec = 2.0 * cross(q.xyz, pN);
pN = pN + q.w * tempVec + cross(q.xyz, tempVec);
pN = inverse(VM) * pN;
```

My question is, do I have the right to rewrite the equation like this ?

```
vec_res = (inverse(VM) * conversion_to_matrix(q) * VM) * vec_input
```

Where conversion_to_matrix is the rotation matrix calculated as explained in: http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/quaternionToMatrix/

If no, what is the math to be used behind ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
vec_res = (inverse(VM) * conversion_to_matrix(q) * VM) * vec_input
```

Is perfectly valid.
The problem is...

```
inverse(VM) * conversion_to_matrix(q) * VM
```

is NOT equal to

```
conversion_to_matrix(q)
```

Therefore you have to keep the original equation in its entirety.

Comment: Why did you copy my answer almost exactly?

Comment: Because your answer wasn't clear and you didn't accept my edits.

Comment: I don't see any suggested edits. Your answer states exactly what mine states, how can yours be clearer?

Comment: Ok then i must have made a mistake somewhere since it is not working. I mean, the behavior is not the same before transforming the equation. 
Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Note that multiplying your vector with

```
inverse(VM) * conversion_to_matrix(q) * VM
```

is not the same as multiplying it with

```
conversion_to_matrix(q)
```

since matrix multiplication is not commutative. So you really have to compute the entire matrix given in the first formula above.

Comment: I know, but I cannot manage to find the right math for it. Any hint about this ?

Comment: @fr4nk: You need the matrix `Q = conversion_to_matrix(q)`, and then you need a matrix-matrix multiplication routine to compute `inv(VM) * Q * VM`. What step are you having trouble with?